# Implementation of finding people around using Parse?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am currently building a location-based app using Parse as backend. I have already read the code example "Anywall".  My problems are as follows:

1. I have created a class "Location" which contains the parse Geopoint object sent by a Parse user and a pointer of that user. Since a Parse user continuously send her/his coordinate to the class "Location", I may probably get records with the same user but different geopoints if the user keep staying where he stays. So when using withinKilometers method to query nearby users, I will probably get duplicate users. Certainly I can handle this situation on client side. But if a user frequently send her/his location to Parse, there will be more duplicate users thus waste bandwidth.
2. I also need pagination since the view is a listview. And I am develop an android app.

What is the solution for this? Can guys give a detailed solution?